# Pass variable to next View Controller

Tags: swift3, viewcontroller

I want to pass a variable from one view controller to another.
First View Controller looks like this and the segue gets triggered correctly and the new view controller gets displayed.

```
@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let timerVC = TimerViewController()

    timerVC.secondsPassed = textfield_seconds.text!

    navigationController?.pushViewController(timerVC, animated: true)

}
```

On the next View Controller (TimerViewController) I declared a variable in the class header

```
var secondsPassed:String!
```

and in viewDidLoad I just want to print the value to the console and all I receive is a 'nil'.

I looked through various tutorials but I seem not to find the correct answer for this to get it work.

Anyone around with a clue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have a segue connected to the button? In that case I don't think the `IBAction` actually runs. You should remove the segue since you are already calling `pushViewController`.

Comment: Yes, there was a segue connected. I removed it, but now nothing happens. No new view controller is displayed and just the button is indicating that it has been pressed. I am still confused. How can something this simple be so hard o_O?

Comment: Ah, then you don't have a UINavigationController embedded, right? posting an answer now.

Comment: No, I do not have a UINavigationController. Would it make sense to mark my storyboards and embed them into a storyboard via the menu? Would that solve my issues?

Comment: You can either1. not embed in a navigation controller and use my answer or 2. embed in a navigation controller and remove the segue. Either of those will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I still do not get it. :-( Where do you get all the know how from? I can not really find explanations that fit my level of coding. it is either to easy or way to hard to understand,... so annoying :-/

Comment: personally I don't think swift and iOS is the first thing you should learn. Swift has so many little cool things and it implicitly does this and that. It can be quite confusing for a beginner. I think Java is a better first language (it's mine). It has relatively less bells and whistles. Also, always Google and read SO answers and people's blog posts and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already are using a segue, you can remove this line that presents the controller (you don't seem to have a `navigationController` anyway):

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(timerVC, animated: true)
```

Now the correct way to pass data to another VC using segues is this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? TimerViewController {
        vc.secondsPassed = textfield_seconds.text!
    }
}
```